# How to get the travelTime of an EKEvent instance

Tags: swift, eventkit, ekevent, ekeventstore

I'd like to get the travel time of a calender event (EKEvent), but I get this error: `Value of type 'EKEvent' has no member 'travelTime'`.

When I print an EKEvent, I get this:

[image: Screenshot of console showing an EKEvent with travelTime]

```
EKEvent <0x79f6f460>
{
     EKEvent <0x79f6f460>
{    title =        Test; 
     location =     Foobar; 
     calendar =     EKCalendar <0x7ba6f9a0> {title = Calendar; type = Local; allowsModify = NO; color = #1BADF8;}; 
     alarms =       (null); 
     URL =          (null); 
     lastModified = 2016-04-25 17:56:58 +0000; 
     startTimeZone =    Europe/Amsterdam (GMT+2) offset 7200 (Daylight); 
     startTimeZone =    Europe/Amsterdam (GMT+2) offset 7200 (Daylight) 
}; 
     location =     Foobar; 
     structuredLocation =   EKStructuredLocation <0x79e722e0> {title = Foobar; address = (null); geo = (null); abID = (null); routing = (null); radius = 0.000000;}; 
     startDate =    2016-04-25 19:15:00 +0000; 
     endDate =      2016-04-25 20:15:00 +0000; 
     allDay =       0; 
     floating =     0; 
     recurrence =   (null); 
     attendees =    (null); 
     travelTime =   30 minutes; 
     startLocation =    (null);
};
```

Does anyone have an idea about what's going on? (I can access stuff like the title of startDate just fine)

Comment: You should probably update your question with the NSLog above as text, instead of an image.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the log as text.

Comment: im curios, can you  access any of the other keys like startDate, endDate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to return the travel time property in terms of seconds:

```
 let travelTime = yourEKEvent.valueForKey("travelTime")!
```

Apparently there is no accessible `travelTime` property in the `EKEvent` class so i guess its somewhere in its super classes. In the built in iOS calendar when you add travel time to an event the detail to the option reads:

> Event alerts will take this time into account and your calendar will be blocked during this time

[image]

After looking at the`EKAlarms` documentation I think it may be stored in the `relativeOffset` property. The alarms should be stored in the `EKCalendar` super class.

**You can also update the value by the set value method:**

`yourEKEvent.setValue(300, forKey: "travelTime")`

and then re-save the event using a method like this:

```
    func updateEvent(event: EKEvent)
{
    do {
        try eventStore.saveEvent(event, span: .ThisEvent)
        savedEventId = event.eventIdentifier

    } catch {
        print("Bad things happened")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: Swift 5: `yourEKEvent.value(forKey: "travelTime")!`